# How to remove GHC 9.2.1 on Windows 10 that has been installed via chocolatey?

Tags: haskell, ghc, chocolatey

I have installed ghc 9.2.1 via chocolatey on Windows 10. I tried to remove it with `choco uninstall ghc` and it says that one package has been removed. But I can see that ghc has not been removed since the folder C:\tools\ghc-9.2.1 as well as folder `C:\tools\msys64` are not empty. When I issue the command `ghc --version` I get the following (meaning that ghc is still there).

```
PS C:\Users\ephra> ghc --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 9.2.1
```

However, issuing `choco uninstall ghc`, I get this:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>choco uninstall ghc
Chocolatey v0.11.3
Uninstalling the following packages:
ghc
ghc is not installed. Cannot uninstall a non-existent package.
```

Should I remove simply the folder `C:\tools\` (with subfolders `ghc-9.2.1` and `msys64`)?

Comment: Perhaps this question would be better aimed at the chocolatey issue tracker. If chocolatey claims to uninstall a package but doesn't, that seems like a bug, not something where we can just say "oh, you're using it wrong, try this instead".

Comment: Out of interest, why are you uninstalling 9.2.1? Are you reverting to an earlier release, or abandoning Haskell altogether?

Comment: @AntC: I have installed an earlier release (the recommended ghc 8.10.7) via GHCup, in order to avoid dependency issues when building projects.